# Handling dependency in MVVM architecture

Tags: wpf, mvvm

First MVVM WPF project, so I am probably asking a common question, but I can't find the search magic for an answer.

I have a number of views, and when a certain command is invoked in one of them I need to disable some of the other views. I put a boolean flag in my data model indicating whether they should be enabled, and the other views can see that change through their ViewModel bindings. But the model is not "INotifyPropertyChanged" so when I change that flag in the data model, nothing will update. So what is required to make this happen?

Comment: Get your Model to implement INPC? Having your Model implement INPC is not a bad thing. If you use MVVM Light, inherit the Model from `ObservableObject` rather than `ViewModelBase` which is what VM's inherit from.

Comment: That would be logical, Viv! (Just didn't know if that's the done thing).

Comment: or you can simply raise some event after you update your data in model... your other views will be subscribed so when you raise that event then your views read data from model and update accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM a way to decouple view-models is to use an [event aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html). When you command executes it raises an event. The other view-models that are interested in this event have a subscription set up and will get notified when the event fires.

A very nice event aggregator implementation is seen in [an answer to the question named "Event Aggregator Implementation Sample / Best Practices"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756787/98607).

Answer (score 1):

The comments already suggest one possible solution: implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your models.

However, there is another solution that enables you to keep your models simpler and your architectural layers less coupled. If your VMs instead depend on each other and treat the model as a simple data bucket, they can be notified via their own INPC implementations rather than relying on the model. In other words, if VM A needs to know when model X changes, it can instead attach establish a relationship with VM B (which wraps model X) instead of depending directly on model X.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what your View-Model is for!  Although there is nothing wrong with making your model implement INPC, you certainly shouldn't expect, or rely on it.  Your View-Model is the bridge between the UI-agnostic model and the user interface.

A typical way to approach your problem is to create View-Model classes that wrap around your Model classes that DO implement INPC.  You bind to the View-Models directly allowing changes in the values to be reflected in the UI through INPC.